# I removed the hash from (URL), I got page not found 404

Tags: jquery, html, window.location

I created a navbar for one page scroll website. all works fine.
I change the URL from : http://example.com**#sectionb**, to http://example.com/**sectionb**

when i click on the other item in the navbar the page scroll to the wanted section and the url change to http://example.com/**sectionc**

to do that i use :

```
id = $(this).attr('href');
var link = id.split('#')[1];
window.history.pushState("", "Title", link);
```

**However the problem is**, when i refresh the page using the url http://example.com**/sectionb** it shows **page not found 404** !! But when i use http://example.com**/#sectionb** it shows the **"sectionb"**

**What i want is when i refresh the page with http://example.com/sectionb, to see the section "sectionb"**

**html :**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="sectiona" data-uri="1">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="sectionb" data-uri="2">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="sectionc" data-uri="3">Third</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="sections">
  <section id="sectiona"></section>
  <section id="sectionb"></section>
  <section id="sectionc"></section>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
    var sections = $('section')
  , nav = $('nav')
  , nav_height = nav.outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

  sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
        bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
    if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
      nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
      sections.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});

nav.find('a').on('click', function (e) {
  var $el = $(this)
    , id = $el.attr('href');
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - nav_height
  }, 500);

  var link = id.split('#')[1];
  window.history.pushState("", "Title", link);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: When you reload the page, the browser makes a new request for the current address - so you have to first of all make your server answer that request correctly, and not with a 404.

Comment: it shows ==>  Not Found   The requested URL /nav/5 was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/7.1.9 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: So why can't you just make your life simple by leaving them alone? Instead of removing `#` and then putting it back afterwards?

Comment: You _created_ "fake" URLs, so now you are also responsible for answering requests made by trustful clients properly. When `http://example.com/sectionb` is requested, then your server must return your application (your main HTML document), and it needs to be shown scrolled to the section B element already. If you don't implement that, then you simply made a promise with those fake URLs that you are breaking pretty much immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Your code just updates the URL in the history. That, in no way, means that the URL you've placed there is valid.

- `http://example.com/#sectionb` means **locate the element** with an `id` of `sectionb` in the default document in the domain root and navigate (scroll) to it.
- `http://example.com/sectionb` means **load the default document** *in the sub-directory* called `sectionb`

You seem to be stating that when the original URL is:

```
http://example.com/#sectionb
```

your code changes it to:

```
http://example.com/sectionb
```

and, then you want that URL to navigate to:

```
http://example.com/#sectionb
```

This seems circular. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I pushed you over 28k :D

Comment: It would probably help OP if you told him what he needs to do on the server-side to solve the problem.

Comment: @connexo It's unclear to me what the real problem actually is. It seems to me that none of the URL manipulation is necessary at all.

Comment: Ah I see. I was expecting the context of an spa.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved i edit my controller : http://example.com/{sect}

```
    /**
     * Matches /*
     *
     * @Route("/{sec}", name="home")
     * 
     */
    public function index($sec = null) 
    {
        //return new Response('Test');
        //dump($sec);
        return $this->render('pages/nav.html.twig', [
            'sec' => $sec,
        ]);
    }
```

Thank's

Comment: It would have been nice if your question indicated that you were using a controller and routes.